# How to capture video from 1x & 0.5x camera at the same time in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I have created a custom camera where I am able to capture videos in high quality (4k).
I am looking to incorporate the feature like native camera has wherein there is a button to change from normal camera (1x) to wide angle camera (0.5x) while the camera is recording.
How can I add this feature in my custom camera app? or is it possible to add it?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Just toggle the lens correction to green and refresh the Camera app